# InAppSettingsKit Localization works in Settings.app, but not in my App

Tags: ios, iphone, localization, settings.bundle, inappsettingskit

My app supports four (4) languages, (en, es, fr, and de).

My Settings.bundle is configured as such:

```
Settings.bundle
  - Root.plist
  -en.lproj
    --Root.strings
  -es.lproj
    --Root.strings
  -fr.lproj
    --Root.strings
  -de.lproj
    --Root.strings
```

Each Root.strings is exactly the same with the exception of the string values being localized.

All of this works as I would expect (in the simulator).  As I switch languages in Settings.app->General->International->Language, the Settings.app portion of IASK displays the appropriate language.

In my app however, I only get English regardless of the language setting I selected.

Does anyone have any suggestions where I should look for help on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have xx.lproj folders also on the root level of your app. The OS uses these to determine the available localizations of an app.

Comment: Thank you Ortwin!  To expand on your answer, I added a folder for each language and then copied the InfoPlist.strings file into each folder as well.  Everything then just worked.  Nice product, by the way.